# Composing non-distributive monads in recursion-schemes

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

One of my favourite things about the recursion schemes in Haskell are the generalised morphisms (`gcata` etc.) that allow interleaving (co-)monadic computations with recursion, using a monad transformer library. For example, as described in [this](https://blog.sumtypeofway.com/posts/recursion-schemes-part-6.html) great blog post.

However, I've run into a problem; to be able to use these functions we need the (co-)monads to be (co-)sequentiable. Consider a type signature for `gana`:

```hs
gana : Monad m => (forall z . m (f z) -> f (m z)) -> (a -> f (m a)) -> a -> b
```

The first argument essentially says that `m` must have a `sequence` operator.

Unfortunately, I've found that in practice, there are monads which are **not** distributive. For example:

- A monad representing a database transaction. When aborted, the transaction can be rolled back; if sequenced, it can only be rolled back to the point where it was sequenced.
- A concurrency monad, representing a lock on a resource, or an atomic computation. When sequenced, the lock is lost momentarily.

In this case, it is still possible to write [a specialised recursion scheme](https://youtu.be/Zw9KeP3OzpU?t=4009) that interleaves the monadic execution; but you lose the ability to fuse it using a monad transformer. i.e. if you want to combine such non-distributive monads, they can not be fused using a transformer with the monad/comonad in the f-(co)algebra. Concretely, I couldn't use a monad transformer to combine a `DBTransaction` monad with an apomorphism (`ExceptT/EitherT`); I'd need to write a custom recursion-scheme from scratch.

My question is whether anyone has suggestions for working around this limitation.

Comment: In general, there won't be any transformers for monads that deal with external side-effects (database transactions, concurrency, reading/writing files, etc.). The reason is that a transformer will need to be able to incorporate an arbitrary foreign monad; for example, the `Maybe` monad, which can remove the result value. This means the transformer needs to be able to undo the external effect. But that may be just impossible to implement.